# VirtualBox Host-Only Network loses IP configuration

Tags: virtualbox

I'm using the VirtualBox Host-Only Network to communicate between host (Windows 7 Pro x64) and guest (CentOS 6.4). The host uses a static IP:

[image: Static IP Host-Only adapter 192.168.56.1]

I've been using this configuration for months, never had any trouble.

Suddenly this morning, I couldn't connect to my guest. I traced the source of the problem to the Host-Only Network connection, which strangely did not use the IP configuration requested:

[image: IP configuration Host-Only adapter]

So I temporarily reverted to `Obtain an IP address automatically`, then set my static IP again, and it finally picked `192.168.56.1` as expected. Temporary glitch, I thought. An hour later though, same problem. The IP address was set back to an `Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address`.

Anyone already experienced that?

I've updated a few days ago to VirtualBox 4.2.18, and yesterday evening Windows installed 24 updates.

Could this be a VirtualHost or Windows bug, or did I miss something there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be a bug.

Anyway, I realized I don't need the host to have a static IP anymore (all servers are hosted on the guests, which do have static IP addresses).

So I reverted to `Obtain an IP address automatically` and everything is back to normal.